# How to install Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I installed Sphinx by pip.

However, I cannot start Sphinx.

```
user:~ $ sphinx-quickstart
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "user/anaconda/bin/sphinx-quickstart", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Sphinx==1.2.3', 'console_scripts', 'sphinx-quickstart')()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 552, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2671, in load_entry_point
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'sphinx-quickstart') not found
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using anaconda always try their packages first

- pip uninstall sphinx
- conda install sphinx